# Tropical Trade Stock Trading

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, options

Is Tropical Trade a valid stock trading company?  I would like to start investing but I want to know the validity of the trading company.

Comment: Are you talking about [this TropicalTrade](https://www.tropicaltrade.com/), the binary options seller with the terrible website (at least on mobile)?

Comment: The website is okay on desktop

Answer (score 5):

No, it's a binary options trading website. Dependent on your country you will have better options for buying shares for investments. Binary options are gambling tools.

Comment: Binary Options = Scam. Pretty smart if you ask me.